# Get String from <div> without tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML code as below:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="title">
        <a id="hlAdv" class="title" href="./sample.aspx">
            <font size=2>Pretty Beauty Fiesta -1st Avenue Mall!</font>
        </a>
    </div>
    19<sup>th</sup> ~ 21<sup>st</sup> Apr 2013
</div>
```

I am now using Python and I try to get out the date using BeatifulSoup. What I expect is:

```
19th ~ 21st Apr 2013
```

I tried:

```
find("div", {"class":"content"}).text
```

Output:

```
Pretty Beauty Fiesta -1st Avenue Mall!19th ~ 21st Apr 2013
```

And,

```
find("div", {"class":"content"}).div.nextSibling
```

Output:

```
19
```

I tried to use more nextSibling to get the content, but I still cannot get "st Apr 2013" correctly.

How can I get the data I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? It uses `element.nextSiblingGenerator` to walk through the elements following the div you care about, and ignores the None at the end.

```
d = s.find('div', {'class':'content'}).div

def all_text_after(element):
    for item in element.nextSiblingGenerator():
        if not item:
            continue
        elif hasattr(item, 'contents'):
            for c in item.contents:
                yield c
        else:
            yield item

text_parts = list(all_text_after(d))
# -> [u'\n    19', u'th', u' ~ 21', u'st', u' Apr 2013\n']

print ''.join(text_parts)
# ->     19th ~ 21st Apr 2013
```

Comment: I got a problem on it:
''.join(text_parts)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, generator found

should I add str() to somewhere?

Comment: Is the HTML that gives the error the same as this? It works for me - is it possible you missed the inner loop over item.contents? It's needed to flatten out the nested elements. That might behave the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you want all text that *follows* a given tag in your `div`.

You want to use [`.next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) in a loop here:

```
content_div = soup.find('div', class_='content')
text = []
for elem in content_div.div.next_siblings:
    try:
        text.extend(elem.strings)
    except AttributeError:
        text.append(elem)
text = ' '.join(text).strip()
```

`.next_siblings` is a generator that simply produces the chain of `.next_sibling` attributes, including `NavigableString` elements.

results in:

```
>>> ''.join(text).strip()
u'19th ~ 21st Apr 2013'
```

How you handle whitespace here can be a little tricky; stripping *afterwards* works best for this specific example, but for others, using `elem.stripped_strings` and `elem.strip()` may work as well.